# Get Twitter profile image

Tags: objective-c, image, twitter, profile

I am making an iPhone application and need to integrate Twitter in it.
I am done with the authentication part, I can post messages but I am not able to retrieve the profile image. Do you have any ideas how this could be accomplished?

Thank you a lot!
George

Comment: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/24142947/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-users-lookup

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used MGTwitterEngine so I can't speak to how to use it to grab a profile image, but it looks like you can get it fairly easily using the Twitter API. Here's how I would grab my own profile image:

Make a call to `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=3257861` (replace the user_id with whoever's profile image it is you want)

Using a JSON framework (I've been using [this](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)), parse the response.

For each tweet in the JSON array, there's a key called `profile_image_url` which holds the profile image.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: Actually, there's a MUCH easier way. Just call this URL `http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/3257861.json`, it'll return the profile image. You can read more about it [here](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/profile_image/%3ascreen_name). I'm leaving the rest up there just for reference (or another way of doing it, albeit not the best way)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the `profile_image` endpoint. Super useful!

Comment: The second api call you used is now outdated

Answer (score 1):

Use the [verrify_credentials](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/account/verify_credentials) API call.